# Integer binding to a custom and reusable UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

In my application I defined a reusable WPF UserControl to select a millisecond quantity. Now I'm stuck because when I modify the quantity, the property in the view model class is not updated.

Here is the how I use the millisecond control:

```
        <view:MillisPeaker
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="5 10"
            Width="200"
            DataContext="{Binding FromMillis}"/>
```

Here is the definition:

```
<UserControl x:Class="gui.view.MillisPeaker"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:gui.view"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Text="{Binding .}"/>
    <Button 
        Grid.Column="1"
        Content="-"/>
    <Button 
        Grid.Column="2"
        Content="+"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is the property in the view model class:

```
public int FromMillis { get; set; }
```

The value is correctly displayed at first, but when I modify the the property the view model is not updated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You better define a dependency property (e.g. "Value") in your user control and bind this instead of the DataContext.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind to `FromMillis` you should implement IPropertyChanged interface or make it a dependency property. Otherwise any change on `FromMillis` will not be propagated.